# ksh88 AIX merge two files based on partial string match in one column

Tags: awk, ksh, aix, printf

Using ksh88 on AIX machine, I've tried a whole slew of things that are ultimately not working.

`File_A` has 2 columns without headers: the user group that created the directory in column 1, and the full file path in column 2, e.g.,:

```
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name
User1234567      /another/file/path/different_dir
User0987654      /some/other/path/another_name
```

`File_B` has 2 columns without headers: the size of the directory in MB in column 1, and the partial path name of the directory in column 2, e.g.,:

```
2183.31     directory_name
1750.09     directory_name/subfolder
1028.14     directory_name/subfolder/sub_subfolder
3658.97     different_dir
2159.62     different_dir/subfolder
1001.01     different_dir/different_subfolder
```

etc.

The catch is that there are duplicate directory names in `File_B` (i.e., `directory_name`, `directory_name/subfolder`, `directory_name/subfolder/sub_subfolder`, ...)

What I want is, in one file, this output (I honestly don't care about the order of the columns, just that they're all present):

```
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name     2183.31
User1234567      /another/file/path/different_dir   3658.97
```

It seems simple enough but I haven't been able to figure it out. The closest I can get is to get the user group and the full path name and the line numbers from both files where the partial match was found, but I can not get the directory size (column 1 from `File_B`) ...

The code that I've settled on that gets me so close but not quite there (cobbled together from SO and various online tutorials), is:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$2]=$1
    next
}
{
    for(i in a) 
        if($2 ~ i) 
            {print $2,a[$2],$1} 
}' file_B file_A
```

which produces a list with duplicates for every line from `File_A` where column 2 from `File_A` has a partial match in column 2 from `File_B`, e.g.:

```
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name
```

(One each for `directory_name`, `directory_name/subfolder`, and `directory_name/subfolder/sub_subfolder`)

I've tried to `print` everything I could think of, but to no avail... `NR,FNR,i,$0,a[$NR],a[$FNR],a[$1],a[$2],$1,$2` ... I've also tried to use `printf` but that didn't work either...

Comment: `based on partial string match in one column` - nice, you deserve an upvote just for that! Seeing an accurate statement of what you want to match on is a breath of fresh air after all the questions we see about matching on "patterns"!

Comment: You say `The catch is that there are duplicate directory names in File_B` but your 1 line of sample input and expected doesn't encompass that catch. Please [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers that "catch" scenario and any others so we have something we can test a potential solution against and get a simple pass/fail result.

Comment: Will do Ed; apologies for any confusion - I see now how ambiguous my statement was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is essentially a join of two database tables. Conveniently, there is a command for that, aptly named `join`.

No need for `awk` here. Note that I have neither `ksh88` nor AIX; this is Bash on Linux, but I quickly checked the [AIX manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/navigation/commands.html) and think it should work.

I prepared this test environment:

```
$ cat filea
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name5
Userwh0c4r36     /fake/file/path/directory_name6
Userwh0c4r37     /fake/file/path/directory_name7
$ cat fileb
1234    directory_name5
2345    directory_name6
3456    directory_name7
```

**Step 1**: Add a column to `filea` consisting of only the last part of the directory pathname:

```
$ sed 's|\(.*\)/\(.*\)|\1/\2 \2|' filea > filea.tmp
$ cat filea.tmp
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name5 directory_name5
Userwh0c4r36     /fake/file/path/directory_name6  directory_name6
Userwh0c4r37     /fake/file/path/directory_name7  directory_name7
```

**Step 2**: Sort both files by the directory name (thanks, Mark Plotnick, for pointing this out):

```
$ sort -k3 filea.tmp > filea.tojoin
$ sort -k2 fileb > fileb.tojoin
```

**Step 3**: Use `join` to join this with `fileb`, based on the directory name in column 3 (`filea`) and column 2 (`fileb`):

```
$ join -1 3 -2 2 filea.tojoin fileb.tojoin > result
$ cat result
directory_name5 Userwh0c4r35 /fake/file/path/directory_name5 1234
directory_name6 Userwh0c4r36 /fake/file/path/directory_name6  2345
directory_name7 Userwh0c4r37 /fake/file/path/directory_name7  3456
```

**Optional step 4**: A `cut` will get rid of the first column, if you don't want it.

Comment: Not just likely, but surely. I had forgotten this little detail.

Comment: This seems to have done it; double-checking now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're trying to do and your sample input/output isn't currently useful for testing with but here's one guess at it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    val = $1                                    # val = Userwh0c4r35 or 2183.31
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")        # Allows spaces in directory names vs using $2
    dir = $0                                    # dir = /fake/file/path/directory_name or directory_name/subfolder
}
NR==FNR {
    sub(".*/","",dir)                           # dir = directory_name
    dir2path[dir] = $0
    dir2grp[dir]  = val
    next
}
{
    sub("/.*","",dir)                           # dir = directory_name
    print dir2grp[dir], dir2path[dir], val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk File_A File_B
Userwh0c4r35    /fake/file/path/directory_name  2183.31
Userwh0c4r35    /fake/file/path/directory_name  12345
Userwh0c4r35    /fake/file/path/directory_name  9876
```

The above assumes that the same `directory_name` can't appear at the end of different paths in File_A (e.g. `/foo/directory_name` and `/bar/directory_name`) and was run on these input files:

```
$ head File_*
==> File_A <==
Userwh0c4r35     /fake/file/path/directory_name

==> File_B <==
2183.31     directory_name
12345       directory_name/subfolder
9876        directory_name/subfolder/sub_subfolder
```

If your directory names can contain tabs then you'd need to use a different output format. If they can contain newlines then you'll need a different input format too.

Comment: Ed, I really appreciate your taking the time to help; I regret that because I gave insufficient context in my question, your answer didn't solve the problem.